# Get offset of stream of audio files

Tags: python, audio

How can I get **offset** of *stream* at audio files such as MP3, FLAC, WAV?

For example, an MP3 file contains *header* and *data* (*stream* mentioned earlier) sections. The *header* starts with 0xfffb (maybe 0xfffa?), and the entire header occupies 4 bytes. Following binaries are the *data* section, and its start position is what I want.

Comment: You either use a library that does it for you, or you write code to decode the file format.

Comment: @barny I tried to find audio-related libraries such as pydub, eyeD3, mutagen and used it, but it doesn't offer functionality what I want.